# BLE Android how to pass characteristics to use in Fragment

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, fragment, characteristics

I got a BLE tutorial working. I can send and receive data on the SPS service, this data TX RX is done in Dialog_BTLE_Characteristics. It looks like the characteristics & services are passed from Activity_BTLE_Services to Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic class using the following commands.

```
Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic dialog_btle_characteristic = new Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic();
dialog_btle_characteristic.setTitle(uuid);
dialog_btle_characteristic.setService(mBTLE_Service);
dialog_btle_characteristic.setCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

then the characteristics are used in Dialog_BTLE_Characteristic class to send data (output):

```
characteristic.setValue(output);
service.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Now I want to send and receive data inside a Fragment. How do I pass that characteristics and services to the Fragment?

Your help will be great.
Marinus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it bad practice to do BLE operations in a fragment. Create a helper class that does the BLE operations and only send decoded data to fragments/actvities for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you were to separate the code into different files you might have a better time moving around.

What I recommend is that you pass the characteristic and device ID to the [fragment using a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/932052):

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("someInt", someString);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);

        return myFragment;
    }

    //-------

    // In the fragment

    getArguments().getInt("someString");
```

I have been writing some pretty abismal code for a few years but it does get a lot of the heavy lifting out the way:

```
    //By the way, I think this is the server, better known as "Central Module", not the peripheral. I've had this misunderstanding until recently and still need to change the code
    public class BLEPeripheral {

        private String deviceId;
        private BLEManager connector;
        private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
        private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
        private BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
        private BluetoothGattService bluetoothGattService = null;
        private HashMap<String, Command<String>> subscriptions;

        private boolean connected = false;

        public boolean isConnected() {
            return connected;
        }

        public BLEPeripheral(BLEManager connector, String deviceId) {
            this.connector = connector;
            this.deviceId = deviceId;

            this.connector.onDisconnected();
            final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) this.connector.getContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

            if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                this.connector.enableBluetooth();
                return;
            }

            if (!this.connector.checkPermission()) return;

            scanForDevice();
        }

        public void scanForDevice() {
            connected = false;
            connector.log("BT ENABLED: SCANNING FOR DEVICES");
            connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.SEARCH_START);
            bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLEScanCallback);
        }

        public void stopScan() {
            connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.SCAN_CANCEL);
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLEScanCallback);
        }

        private final ScanCallback mLEScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
                if (record == null) {
                    connector.log(String.format("Device [%s] has no scan record", device.getAddress()));
                    return;
                }

                String name = record.getDeviceName();
                String UUID = null;

                if (record.getServiceUuids() != null) {
                    for (ParcelUuid pId : record.getServiceUuids()) {
                        if (pId.getUuid().toString().equals(deviceId)) {
                            UUID = pId.getUuid().toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (UUID == null) {
                    if (name != null) connector.log(String.format("Discovered Device [%s]. Continuing search", name));
                    return;
                }
                connector.log(String.format("Peripheral [%s] located on Device [%s]. Attempting connection", UUID, name));
                bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(connector.getContext(), true, mGattCallback);
                stopScan();
                connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.DEVICE_FOUND);
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            }
        };

        private void closeGatt() {
            connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.DICSONNECT);
            connector.onDisconnected();
            if (bluetoothGatt == null) {
                return;
            }
            bluetoothGatt.close();
            bluetoothGatt = null;
            scanForDevice();
        }

        private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            StringBuilder buffer;
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                        connector.onConnectionStateChange(newState);
                        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                            connector.log("Connected to device GATT. Discovering services");
                            connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.DEVICE_CONNECTED);
                            bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                            connector.log("Disconnected from GATT server. Continuing scanning");
                            closeGatt();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                            if (bluetoothGatt.getServices() != null) {
                                connector.log("Services discovered: ["+bluetoothGatt.getServices().size()+"]");
                                for (BluetoothGattService service : bluetoothGatt.getServices()) {
                                    if (service.getUuid().toString().equals(deviceId)) {
                                        bluetoothGattService = service;
                                        connector.onConnected();
                                        connector.log("Service discovered");
                                        connector.log("Attempting characteristic subscription");
                                        connector.subscribeToCharacteristics();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            connector.log(String.format("onServicesDiscovered received: [%s]", status));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                            connector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicRead received: [%s] value: [%s]", characteristic.getUuid().toString(), new String(characteristic.getValue())));
                        } else {
                            connector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicRead fail received: [%s]", status));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
                        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                            connector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicWrite received: [%s] value: [%s]", characteristic.getUuid().toString(), new String(characteristic.getValue())));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                        String packet = new String(characteristic.getValue());
                        if (packet.equals(String.valueOf((char)2))) {
                            buffer = new StringBuilder();
                        } else if (packet.equals(String.valueOf((char)3))) {
                            if (subscriptions == null || subscriptions.size() == 0) return;

                            Command<String> handler = subscriptions.get(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                            if (handler != null) handler.execute(new String(buffer.toString()));
                        } else {
                            buffer.append(packet);
                        }
                    }
                };

        public BluetoothGattService getService() {
            return bluetoothGattService;
        }

        private BluetoothGattCharacteristic findCharacteristicById(String id) {
            if (bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristics() != null) {
                return bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString(id));
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void subscribe(String characteristicId, Command<String> handler){
            if (subscriptions == null) subscriptions = new HashMap<>();
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);

            if (characteristic == null) {
                connector.log("Characteristic does not exist");
                return;
            }
            connected = true;
            connector.reportState(BleManagerStatus.CHARACTERISTIC_SUBSCRIBED);
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

            subscriptions.put(characteristicId, handler);
        }

        public void writeCharacteristic(String characteristicId, String data) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);
            if (characteristic != null) {
                characteristic.setValue(data);
                bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                connector.log(String.format("Wrote [%s] to [%s]", data, characteristicId));
            } else {
                connector.log(String.format("[%s] not found on device", characteristicId));
            }
        }

        public void readCharacteristic(String characteristicId) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);
            if (characteristic == null) return;
            bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
    }
```

[[SOURCE CODE]](https://github.com/qbalsdon/BLE_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/balsdon/bleexample/BLEPeripheral.java)

Then I just need to pass an instance of `BLEManager` in, which is just a simple interface:

```
    public interface BLEManager {
        void log(String message);
        void reportState(BleManagerStatus status);
        void onConnectionStateChange(int newState);
        Context getContext();
        void enableBluetooth();
        void onConnected();
        void subscribeToCharacteristics();
        void onDisconnected();
        boolean checkPermission();
    }
```

[[SOURCE CODE]](https://github.com/qbalsdon/BLE_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/balsdon/bleexample/BLEManager.java)

And your fragment / activity can just implement that. I think this is called an [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), because I'm abstracting the implementation of BLE away from the Android lifecycle.

1. [this a video of one of the things I did with it](https://youtu.be/eY6tNVZGpUA). I built the tank as well :)
2. [here is the Raspberry Pi part](https://hackaday.io/project/26934-bluetooth-low-energy-controlled-tank)

Comment: Please excuse my java, still need to convert it to Kotlin :)

Comment: Thank you Quintin, Its a lot to take in but I will try it

Comment: Quintin, I will come back to you on this one to show you how I understand what to do.

Comment: It took me a long time to come to grips with this stuff too, I've done it all in my spare time - hope you come right